# in linux cli, if someone says 'create this: /george/trees/poppet' how do I know whether 'poppet' is the 3rd directory or a file?

Tags: linux

Clarification:  the directory /george/ exists when I am given the task, and I do know how to read the attribute in cli showing that it is a directory.  The balance of the path requested does not exist, so the only way I can tell if 'poppet' is a file or directory is by convention.  This question comes from an issue I had with interpretation of this line, so am interested in knowing if there is a convention.  This occurred using Ubuntu, but would be relevant in any distro, methinks.

Comment: There are 10 components `drwxrwxrwx`. If the firsr is a `d` -- it's a directory. If the first is a `-`, it's not a directory. As for `poppet` -- without knowing the context you are using it in, there is no way you can tell. You have to know what you need to create. The shell won't do that part for you. If you have some other piece of information, like a partial path of where `poppet` is being copied from, etc.., then you can deduce the nature of it from there. However, without more -- there isn't any way to tell.

Comment: Are you asking how tell if a given path (e.g. `/george`), if it exists, is either a file or directory? Or are you asking something else? What language are you working with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing what "create this" is supposed to mean.  Linux has entirely different commands for the two possibilities: `mkdir` for a directory, `touch` (or numerous other commands that additionally write content) for a file.

Comment: If the expectation is that you can do this with one command, then it is mkdir -p

Comment: I guess I'm reading this as "If I ask a question on a forum and someone says this in their answer do they mean file or directory?" If that's the case then context is really your only bet here. Some files have no extension. If you can't figure out from their answer, try googling "/george/trees/poppet" to see if it pops up anywhere else. Ask for clarification.

Comment: My question (the one I thought I was asking but may not have conveyed clearly) was answered in the first response.  I know how to make a directory and how to make a file and how to interpret the attribute in cli.  I mistakenly interpreted the command as 'create the following directory', which resulted in a failure to load a config file called 'poppet'.  I concluded that those who knew more than I were aware of a convention.  Apparently not, I just guessed wrong.  BTW the context was not known before I debugged my problem.